# Xcode 9.3 build crashes on call with URL scheme (deeplink)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode 9.3 my App crashes when I try to open it over an URL scheme (deeplink) like:  `myapp://somepath`

No problems with Xcode 9.2. I have both Xcode versions installed and exactly the same code crashes with Xcode 9.3 but not with Xcode 9.2. The crash happens right *before* the call arrives to:

```
AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, open : URL, sourceApplication : String?, annotation : Any) -> Bool
```

I have set a breakpoint in this function and it will never reach it, it just crashes before. Here the crashlytics log:

http://crashes.to/s/3237f00bf6a

So any ideas what causes this or how to solve it?

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant portion of the error and symbolicated stacktrace into your question (as text).

Comment: @rmaddy The linked, already answered, question has a really bad title, so it's hard to find it. I extensively searched on SO before asking my question. I suggest to leave my question so others can find it easier.

Comment: That's fine. Being closed as a dupe doesn't mean the question should be deleted. BTW - not my down votes.

Comment: @rmaddy I see, thanks. I have no problem with down votes. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug on Swift4.1
https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-7240

Workaround is to replace function to following:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

Comment: Or replace swift with auld good obj-c ;)